# Polynomial Congruence

Tags: number-theory

Let $\mathbb{p}$ be a prime such that $p=1\:(mod\:4)$.

Find the solutions of the congruence $(x+1)^{2}=-3\:(mod\:p)$.

I am not sure of how to use the property of $p$ in the congruence. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Do you know about quadratic reciprocity?

Answer (score 1):

Your congruence has a solution
iff $-3$ is a square modulo $p$, iff $\bigg(\frac{-3}{p}\bigg)=1$.
This is equivalent to $\bigg(\frac{-1}{p}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{3}{p}\bigg)=1$,
now $\bigg(\frac{-1}{p}\bigg)=1$ since $p\equiv 1 \ ({\sf mod}\ 4).$ Then, by 
quadracic reciprocity, your congruence has a solution iff 
$p\not\equiv (-1) \ ({\sf mod} \ 3)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help however I need to find the solutions, I know they exist but can't identify them.

Comment: What do you mean by "find the solutions" ? There are algorithms to compute them for any particular value of $p$, sure, but there is no simple formula.